# How can I tell Python to write a comma between tuple values?

Tags: python, tuples

This code asks the user to choose some songs, then takes the paths of those songs, and writes them to a text file:

```py
def create_playlist():
    
    playlist_songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=f'C:/Users/{Playlist.username}/Music',filetypes=[('Audio Dateien','.mp3')])
     
    playlist_file = str(filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir=f'C:/Users/{Playlist.username}/Music',filetypes=[('Playlistdatei','.txt')]))
    playlist_file = playlist_file[25: playlist_file.index("' ")]
    with open (playlist_file, 'w') as file:
        print(playlist_songs)
        file.write lines(playlist_songs)
```

However, when I look at the output of my text file, I see that there are missing commas between new paths. On the picture below, the red commas indicate where there should have been an added comma:

[image: screenshot of text file]

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You have a print call there on the string you are writing to the file. Does it have the same problem? If so, that's where you should start your debugging.

Comment: Nah, there is a Comma shown:  https://imgur.com/a/i1n9MXZ

Answer (score 2):

It's because of `writelines` that prints each element of the list as a line separated by a newline `\n`.

You can fix it with this:

```py
all_songs_in_one_string = ";".join(playlist_songs)
file.write(all_songs_in_one_string)
```

Comment: The Problem is now solved, I have found the code by my own, with the solution, that is nearly the smae as yours. with .join

Comment: @baumanager: If the problem is solved, then either post the solution as an answer or simply delete your question — don't just add "Solved" to the question title.

Answer (score 1):

See the following code to read the lines, remove the EOL, and add a comma. Thus placing all on one line separated by commas.

```
def create_playlist():
    playlist_songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(
        initialdir=f'C:/Users/{Playlist.username}/Music',
        filetypes=[('Audio Dateien', '.mp3')])

    playlist_file = str(filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        initialdir=f'C:/Users/{Playlist.username}/Music',
        filetypes=[('Playlistdatei', '.txt')]))
    playlist_file = playlist_file[25: playlist_file.index("' ")]

    with open(playlist_songs, 'r') as f_in:
        print(f_in.read())  # Check the contents of playlist_songs
        with open(playlist_file, 'w') as f_out:
            # Write the formatted contents to playlist_file
            for line in f_in:
                # Remove the end of line using line.strip(), and append a comma
                f_out.write(line.strip() + ',')
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:
`io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`

Comment: I was unable to test because I do not have the original source file. What line number is the error in pleae.

Comment: In the line:  "for line in file".

Comment: Thank you for your try helping me, now I have founded the solution. I have deleted the for loop and added this code, below the print function: 
`a = ","
        x = a.join(playlist_songs)
        file.writelines(x)`

Comment: Great - There is always more than one solution!

Comment: Yes, that's good, else you cold need  a lot more time to solve a problem.